# Connect to AWS DocumentDB from outside (not from VPC or ssh tunneling)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk, aws-documentdb

Is there a possibility to connect to AWS DocumentDB by using our webserver IP address? or something else except these options (not from VPC or ssh tunneling)?

Comment: Are you asking if you can proxy MongoDB client requests via your web server? Or if your clients can connect directly to DocumentDB?

Comment: @jarmod, No. We have a web server and have other projects and need to use AWS DocumentDB in that webserver for these projects

Answer (score 4):

No, at this time DocumentDB only accepts connections from within the VPC. It does not have an option to create a publicly accessible endpoint.

Comment: Is there a reason that the OP couldn't use a Network Load Balancer? (I don't use DocumentDB, so have no idea what restrictions it might place on connections)

Comment: Also, of course, exposing a database to the Internet increases attack surface, so not necessarily a good idea in the first place.

Comment: I am newbie for AWS Cloud. Can we access AWS DocumentDB by web server IP address?

Comment: @KenWalker only if you setup SSH port forwarding.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB. Could you please share document for setup SSH port forwarding if you have?